# Digitally Signing Electron.Net Application

Tags: electron.net

Is there a particular process/steps to go through in order to digitally sign the Electron.net app?  Were there particular settings in the Electron.Manifest.json that can be updated?

I am creating a Windows application - just for distribution amongst some customers - and currently you get various warnings about installing the app.

Has anyone signed the outputted app? I was hoping for some pointers....

Thanks in advance.

Richard